# unbootable Windows 10 (dual boot U 16.04.1 and W10)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

A month ago I reinstalled my Ubuntu 14.04 and replaced it with Ubuntu 16.04.1(clean install). Some days later there was a kernel update and my computer became totally unbootable ('no boot device'). I tried BOOT-REPAIR from live media and reinstalled GRUB2 but boot menu appeared very ugly and hardly readable. I have another ubuntu on a small partition which I use when I want to try something new. After Boot-repair I got access to this second Ubuntu only (my primary Ubuntu and Win10 still unbootable). But it got updates and computer got unbootable again. Then I reinstalled this second Ubuntu and now I can boot my two Ubuntus (boot menu is very very ugly but at least I have OS). In Windows I have only SolidWorks and now I need it.
 This computer is 3 years old and I bought it with Win8 preinstalled. Last year it upgraded to W10. Long time ago I made a backup of EFI partition when everything worked smoothly. After every install and upgrade new files in EFI partition appear and it is a total mess now. I don't know how to use this backup. I made it when there was Windows 8, Ubuntu 13.04 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got two copies of Ubuntu installed, you have one copy of the GRUB binary in the boot process, but two copies of the GRUB configuration and support files (`grub.cfg` and related files) -- one in the `/boot/grub` directory for the first Ubuntu and another in the same directory for the second Ubuntu. (The two Ubuntus have separate filesystems, so you have two `/boot/grub` directories on your computer.) Which GRUB configuration and support files are used depends on how the GRUB binary in the boot process is configured. The last Ubuntu to install or update its GRUB is likely to be the one whose configuration and support files will be used.

This is the source of at least some of your problems -- the GRUB configuration files used at boot time keep changing, so the appearance of GRUB, what options it contains, etc., will also keep changing. Worse, when Ubuntu A reconfigures itself, it might or might not correctly detect options for booting Ubuntu B, and vice-versa. IMHO, this is a fundamental design flaw of GRUB.

One way around the problem is to manually reconfigure GRUB. This will require considerable expertise on GRUB configuration. I don't happen to have any pointers to suitable documentation; I'm afraid that long ago I became so frustrated with GRUB that I gave up on it....

Another approach is to switch to another boot loader. Several EFI boot loaders for Linux are available, as described on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) Most of these options require more manual tinkering than GRUB does, but that manual tinkering is easier than it is with GRUB. My own [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is likely to be the easiest and most flexible of these alternatives. It has the advantage that it scans for kernels at boot time, so it needn't be reconfigured when kernels are updated, so it won't get out of sync with Ubuntu A vs. Ubuntu B when one Ubuntu's kernels are updated.

Comment: This is very interesting. I am not familiar with this stuff an I just hope that BOOT-REPAIR will do the trick. But having another (test) copy of Ubuntu (or some other distro) is a good idea. I always did this on every computer that I used. Now there is BOOT partition where I install boot-loader of my primary Ubuntu and the other boot-loader (secondary Ubuntu) is installed in it's root partition. Nevertheless when some of Ubuntus has update , it changes boot menu and places itself on the first position. But this has never been a problem for me. Everything just worked.

Comment: It is interesting that U 16.04.1 uses GRUB 2.00. Older Ubuntu had Grub 2.02 . So I decided to try  an older distro and today I installed 14.04 (as a second Ubuntu). Now the boot-menu is good-looking (as always) but Windows is still unbootable. Worse, if I turn security boot ON I get message "windows boot loader is blocked by security policy". I think that maybe Boot-repair has changed windows boot loader for some reason and now it is not recognizable. So now I think of reinstalling Windows (or reparation). I don't use it every day but sometimes it is necessary. But first I will try your advice

Comment: Very old versions of Boot Repair would rename the Windows boot loader and put a copy of GRUB in its place. This was done to work around bugs with some EFIs, but was a poor policy as a general rule, so the Boot Repair developers changed it. It's more likely that you're seeing a weird Secure Boot glitch. (That feature causes more problems than it should.) Please re-read my answer; it's imperative that you understand how the different GRUB installations interact, and I don't think you understand that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the more or less the same problem with my dual boot installation on my latest laptop.

My answer will be a pragmatic / empiric one ( sorry for purists )
As a matter of fact, it happens that PCs with windows 8 preinstalled have default boot options which are not dual boot oriented.

First disable all the boot option :
secure boot, 
fast boot, 
uefi support,

All happens in the BIOS.

Then startup the Pc again, and you should be able to access to the grub menu with correct options.

Let me know.

disable secure boot[enter link description here](https://itsfoss.com/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-8/)

Comment: No, Secure boot is OFF. If I change it to ON I get this message: WINDOWS BOOT MANAGER HAS BEEN BLOCKED BY THE CURRENT SECURITY POLICY. If I change EFI to LEGACY BOOT I get a text screen with Grub> prompt.  So the only possibility is Efi and secure boot OFF. This is Acer laptop but I am a long time Ubuntu user (since 2008) and before i bought it I checked linux compatibility. Now this problem started after update. But I think there are too many boot loaders in EFI partition and probably during installation it chooses something wrong. Actually I have boot menu but  Win is not bootable.

Comment: If the computer came pre-installed with Windows 8 or later, ***DO NOT*** "disable... uefi support" (aka enable the Comptability Support Module, or CSM, aka BIOS-mode boot support). This is almost certain to *not* help, and is likely to create new problems. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for information on why this is bad advice.

Comment: I mean Efi is ON and secure boot is OFF

Comment: Ok, well this is beyond my knowledge, and it seems also that your problem is far away from the one I had, if my solution may create more problems ...  ( I'd be curious to know what this is all about when your problem will be solved ).
Good luck !